# How to get Import-codes during TFS-VSTS migration

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration

I am struked by one issue in TFS-VSTS migration i.e., after checking validation import files “ then I want to work with Import-Code section ” where we are decided to import the files which is used for importing the the files to VSTS “Provide the import code assigned to your import” and “Provide the type of input type: DryRun , ProductionRun” . I need How to get Import Code for both types :

Before :
[image]

After :
[image]

I followed this tutorial : "TFS-VSTS migration guide"

Can you please tell me the simplest way for migrating to TFS-VSTS

Answer (score 0):

For migrating TFS-VSTS the best option is just using [TFS Database Import Service](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-overview).

As long as you're on a supported version(*TFS 2017 Update 1/ Update 2*), you can take your **Team Project Collection** and have it directly imported into VSTS, with full fidelity migration of all data.

> **ImportType:** the type of the import to VSTS that you wish to run. For a dry run you can provide ‘**DryRun**’ and production runs should
>   provide ‘**ProductionRun**’ as the value.

Why you need both types in one go? I'm afraid it is not reasonable. You could only select one type in import type. A **Dry Run** is more like a practice run, which is a testing process where the effects of a possible failure are intentionally mitigated.  Such as: [Do a dry run of your TFS upgrade in a pre-production environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/pre-production)

Even though there is no directly related description in the migration guide. Guess the production run is corresponding to the "really" migration. You could choose either you need a dry run in your environment before you actually did the move or not.

Comment: @Patrick-Thanks for your reply, can you please tell me "How to get import-Code for DryRun"

Answer (score 0):

You have to request the code from this link: [TFS Database Import Service](https://microsoftdevelopers.typeform.com/to/qnIWqW).
[image]